# Optimize Pandas Dataframe concat method for very large sparse data

Tags: pandas, performance, optimization, sparse-matrix, numba

Given:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_rnd_df(row:int=10, col:int=7): # generate random Sparse Pandas dataframe
    np.random.seed(0)
    d=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(row,col)).astype(np.float32)
    d[d < 3] = np.nan
    df=pd.DataFrame(data=d,
                    index=[f"ip{i}" for i in np.random.choice(range(max(row, 10)), row, replace=False) ],
                    columns=[f"col_{c}" for c in np.random.choice(range(max(col, 10)), col, replace=False) ],
                    dtype=pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32), # sparse: memory efficient xxx but SUPER SLOW xxx
                )
    df.index.name='usr'
    return df
    
def get_df_concat(dfs):
    t=time.time()
    dfc=pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, sort=True) # vstack dfs=[df1, df2,..., dfN], sort=True: sort columns
    print(f"elapsed_time [concat]{time.time()-t:>{12}.{4}f} sec")

    t=time.time()
    dfc=dfc.groupby(level=0) # groupby index
    print(f"elapsed_time [groupby]{time.time()-t:>{11}.{4}f} sec")

    t=time.time()
    dfc=dfc.sum() # <<<========== Time Consuming ==========>>> 
    print(f"elapsed_time [sum]{time.time()-t:>{15}.{4}f} sec")

    t=time.time()
    dfc=dfc.sort_index(key=lambda x: ( x.to_series().str[2:].astype(int) ))
    print(f"elapsed_time [sort idx]{time.time()-t:>{10}.{4}f} sec")

    return dfc
```

I apply concatenation using my helper function `get_df_concat(dfs)` for several pandas dataframe [`Sparse`] in which columns and indices are sorted. For two small sample pandas dataframe, it works reasonably fine as intended:

```
df1=get_rnd_df(row=8, col=7) # small sample random dataframe
        col_0   col_6   col_4   col_2   col_5   col_3   col_8
usr                             
ip3     5.0     NaN     3.0     3.0     7.0     9.0     3.0
ip5     5.0     NaN     4.0     7.0     6.0     8.0     8.0
ip0     NaN     6.0     7.0     7.0     8.0     NaN     5.0
ip6     9.0     8.0     9.0     4.0     3.0     NaN     3.0
ip2     5.0     NaN     NaN     3.0     8.0     NaN     3.0
ip8     3.0     3.0     7.0     NaN     NaN     9.0     9.0
ip9     NaN     4.0     7.0     3.0     NaN     7.0     NaN
ip7     NaN     NaN     4.0     5.0     5.0     6.0     8.0

df2=get_rnd_df(row=5, col=11) # small sample random dataframe
        col_4   col_10  col_5   col_0   col_9   col_2   col_8   col_6   col_3   col_7   col_1
usr                                             
ip3     5.0     NaN     3.0     3.0     7.0     9.0     3.0     5.0     NaN     4.0     7.0
ip5     6.0     8.0     8.0     NaN     6.0     7.0     7.0     8.0     NaN     5.0     9.0
ip0     8.0     9.0     4.0     3.0     NaN     3.0     5.0     NaN     NaN     3.0     8.0
ip6     NaN     3.0     3.0     3.0     7.0     NaN     NaN     9.0     9.0     NaN     4.0
ip2     7.0     3.0     NaN     7.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     4.0     5.0     5.0     6.0

%%time
df_concat=get_df_concat(dfs=[df1, df2])
        col_0   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4   col_5   col_6   col_7   col_8   col_9   col_10
usr                                             
ip0     3.0     8.0     10.0    0.0     15.0    12.0    6.0     3.0     10.0    0.0     9.0
ip2     12.0    6.0     3.0     5.0     7.0     8.0     4.0     5.0     3.0     0.0     3.0
ip3     8.0     7.0     12.0    9.0     8.0     10.0    5.0     4.0     6.0     7.0     0.0
ip5     5.0     9.0     14.0    8.0     10.0    14.0    8.0     5.0     15.0    6.0     8.0
ip6     12.0    4.0     4.0     9.0     9.0     6.0     17.0    0.0     3.0     7.0     3.0
ip7     0.0     0.0     5.0     6.0     4.0     5.0     0.0     0.0     8.0     0.0     0.0
ip8     3.0     0.0     0.0     9.0     7.0     0.0     3.0     0.0     9.0     0.0     0.0
ip9     0.0     0.0     3.0     7.0     7.0     0.0     4.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

The problem is that my real data is so large that it takes many hours to accomplish concatenation `sum()` method specifically, given sufficient available memory:

```
df1=get_rnd_df(row=int(7e+5), col=int(2e+8)) # resembles my real data
df2=get_rnd_df(row=int(9e+6), col=int(1e+9)) # resembles my real data

%%time
df_concat=get_df_concat(dfs=[df1, df2]) # SUPER SLOW & time-consuming!!!
```

Is there some better alternative to accomplish such concatenation more efficiently? I wonder if there could be SciPy `csr_matrix` to help me out for faster implementation?

PS. I take advantage of `pd.SparseDtype("float32", fill_value=np.nan)` to enure it fits in my available memory.

### UPDATE

Thanks to @RomanPerekhrest, I now optimize the concatenation, specifically the `sum()` method using `numba` engine in Pandas:

```
def get_df_concat_optimized(dfs):
    dfc=pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, sort=True).astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32)) # dfs=[df1, df2,..., dfN], sort=True: sort columns
    dfc=dfc.groupby(level=0) # groupby index
    dfc=dfc.sum(engine="numba", # <<=== saves time using NUMBA engine!
                engine_kwargs={'nopython': True, 'parallel': True, 'nogil': False},
                ).astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32, fill_value=0.0,))
    dfc=dfc.sort_index(key=lambda x: ( x.to_series().str[2:].astype(int) )).astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32, fill_value=0.0))
    return dfc
```

and here is the time comparison for some fairly large random sparse dataframes using my inefficient `get_df_concat(dfs)` approach and the optimized `get_df_concat_optimized(dfs) approach:

```
df1=get_rnd_df(row=int(6e2), col=int(9e2))
df2=get_rnd_df(row=int(2e2), col=int(7e2))

%%time
df_concat_opt=get_df_concat_optimized(dfs=[df1, df2])
CPU times: user 2.32 s, sys: 11.6 ms, total: 2.33 s
Wall time: 2.47 s

%%time
df_concat=get_df_concat(dfs=[df1, df2])
elapsed_time [concat]      0.2443 sec
elapsed_time [groupby]     0.0008 sec
elapsed_time [sum]        67.2486 sec <<< time consuming >>>
elapsed_time [sort idx]    0.2136 sec
CPU times: user 1min 6s, sys: 721 ms, total: 1min 7s
Wall time: 1min 7s
```

Comment: I get `numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 104. GiB for an array with shape (700000, 20000) and data type int64` right on the 1st df generation with `df1=get_rnd_df(row=int(7e+5), col=int(2e+4))`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest well I have enough memory to execute that part, but you could decrease the size `df1=get_rnd_df(row=int(1e+3), col=int(2e+3))` or even smaller to ensure it fits into your memory. My problem is on the concatenation part which is quite inefficient

Comment: There's a lot going on in `df.concat` - keeping track of row and column indices as well as values.  And you have this pandas sparse object.  A `csr` sparse matrix may be simpler, but may not have enough row/col info.  You have to use sparse versions of v/hstack, which convert the matrices to `coo` format, and make a new `coo` matrix from their component arrays.  I don't know enough about the pandas equivalents to say whether they are better or  worse.

Comment: @hpaulj It's not `df.concat` causes the most slowdown, but `groupby` + `sum` + `sort_index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimization points:

- a small one: prefer [`numpy.random.Generator`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator), it's recommended, and in general, I noticed that it works a bit faster than `np.random.<func>`
- operate on numerical index/columns labels. Then, add the needed prefixes at the end at once (vectorizably). That will speed up the processing in general.
- recalling the previous point, eliminate custom sorting of columns, as they can be sorted right on concatenation phase with setting `sort` param: `pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, sort=True)`
- eliminate index sorting with `sort_index`, as `pd.DataFrame.groupby` will sort group keys by default
- boost performance of [`groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) by selecting `numba` (as `engine`) for JIT compiled code with parallel computations (`{'nopython': True, 'parallel': False}`)

I tested on 2 dataframes each of size (`row=int(1e+3), col=int(2e+3)`), the former/initial solution finished in 144 seconds on my machine.
Whereas the optimized approach ran in about **8** sec (as Numba will have some function compilation overhead). But all subsequent calls are running in 2.6 seconds, that's **55X** speedup.

The full optimized version:

```
def get_rnd_df(row=10, col=7):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    a = rng.integers(low=0, high=10, size=(row, col)).astype("float32")
    a[a < 3] = np.nan

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=a,
                      index=rng.choice(range(max(row, 10)), row, replace=False),
                      columns=rng.choice(range(max(col, 10)), col, replace=False),
                      dtype=pd.SparseDtype("float32", fill_value=np.nan),
                      )

    df.index.name = 'usr'
    return df

def get_df_concat(dfs):
    df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, sort=True)  # dfs=[df1, df2, df3, ..., dfN]
    df = df.groupby(level=0).sum(engine="numba",
                                 engine_kwargs={'nopython': True,
                                                'parallel': True})

    df.index = 'ip' + df.index.astype(str)
    df.columns = 'col_' + df.columns.astype(str)

    return df

t0 = time.time()

df1=get_rnd_df(row=int(1e+3), col=int(2e+3)) # resembles my real data
df2=get_rnd_df(row=int(1e+3), col=int(2e+3)) # resembles my real data
df_concat=get_df_concat(dfs=[df1, df2])

print('time spent: ', time.time() - t0)
```

---

```
time spent:  2.636758327484131
```

Comment: Your answer works super faster than my inefficient implementation, appreciate your time and effort! Just an observation though: I guess `df.index = 'ip' + df.index.astype(str)` and `df.columns = 'col_' + df.columns.astype(str)` seems redundant since `pd.concat(..., sort=True)` takes care of sorting the columns

Comment: @FaridAlijani, you're welcome. As for prefixes, as they were added in your initial approach, I thought that namings was necessary for you.